# 2 Different Javascripts - Only 1 Works at a Time

Tags: javascript

I have 2 scripts on one page and I can only get one to work at a time.  I am not very familiar with using javascript so I hope this is an easy fix.  After attempting to search for an answer, I decided that I better just ask and put my code up.

Any constructive comments and answers are appreciated.  Thank you.

Thank you in advance.

```
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Content2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p><strong>Click this tab again to close the content pane.</strong>
        </p>
        <p>Content 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    document.write('<script language="javascript" src="http://www.example.com/test.js"><\/script>');
   </script>

</body>
```

Comment: Why is your `<head>` is outside of the `<html>` element?

Comment: I didn't copy the entire source code... my bad

Comment: I meant body instead of html, I will fix it.

Comment: Why are you using `document.write` instead of just using the `<script>` tag? Also, define "doesn't work". What happens? What's in the JS console?

Comment: The 2nd script is working (at bottom)

Comment: Thank you all for your help and input.  As I mentioned, I don't do a lot with Javascript so I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1):

The first script seems fine, the second one, not.
By writing it to the document it is not executed immediately...

Just do it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/test.js"></script>
```

However a more detaile derror-description would be useful for a faster and more professional help. How can we know what is not workting properly? I am just guessing by the code you provided here what could not work.

What is test.js supposed to do at all?

@Edit:

If the second script is working I still recommend do it the way I explained above...

Hoever if the first script is not working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Do it this way, the first script is never executed becauwe you put it in a function and never called it.

Comment: That is currently a private file so I couldn't display it.  Your answer worked fine.  Thank you very much

Comment: Actually, you're right, the second one is working but the first one is still not working correctly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "the first script is never executed because you put it in a function and never called it"?

Comment: You defined the script in a general function, not plain code. Functions must be called before they get executed, if you never really programmed procedural or objectorientated before you cannot really understand that issue. However If you use my "document.ready" function this automatically triggers when the document is fully loaded. This should work, if not something else is wrong with your plugin and/or its usuage but I cannot determine that from this code pieces. Is the "#tabs" plugin from jquerytools.org or JqueryUI?

Comment: Yes, it's from jqueryui

Comment: When I remove the 2n Javascript code, the code for the tabs works fine.

Comment: Well then you seem to have two conflicting scripts like the second one deleting an element you need or something like that.

If the second one changes some Html Elements the first one might not work anymore but since "test.js" is a blackbox for me my ability to support you ends here cause I cannot tell you what is wrong. Try debugging with Firebug console or so, Sorry.

Fact is is both scripts work independend from each other you have a conflict between them.